# Trouble getting external monitor to connect to laptop

Tags: laptop, external-display, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS M1530 whose display card seems to have fried out. Nothing shows up on the screen although I know the laptop boots up just fine. I tried connecting the laptop to an external monitor using the 15-pin cable and it worked the first time. The moment I restarted the laptop, the external monitor started displaying "input not supported" error. I am at a loss as to what to do.

FWIW, I use Fn+F8 key combo to toggle between my laptop's screen and the external monitor.

In many websites it is said that this happens because there is a resolution mismatch between what the laptop's screen can show and what the external monitor can show. Even if that is the case, how do I fix it given that I can't see any darn thing on my laptop? Also, why did it work the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting without the external monitor attached. Then attach the external monitor and close the lid to the laptop. That should force the video to the external screen.

If you can't see anything then there's a good chance the card is shot.

Comment: Do you mean that as a solution to "input not supported" error?

Comment: NO just trying to get it back to working on the external monitor. If you can manage to get it to show you anything you should then be able to adjust the settings to make the screen work consistently.

Comment: A few mins ago I tried it but I didn't close the lid. Maybe I will do that but if I do see something what kind of settings must I adjust?

Comment: I have no clue but you might be able to resolve the resolution mismatch by adjusting the video card resolution to a supported setting.

Comment: Starting with the lid closed is your best shot. fn f8 cant always properly switch over.  I was working on a laptop fridy that a user cracked the lcd.  If i didnt either shut the case or fn f8 at the boot menu from bios it wouldent display on the external monitor.  dell's can be touchy about which display they use.  also if that doesnt matter then the video card/systemboard is shot. the lattitudes have a buit in card with a daughter card for the side ports including video.  the precisions have a seperate video card that is replaceable even then we some times have to do both systemboard and vid.

Answer (score 0):

You could RDP into the machine and edit the resolution settings for the external monitor in the registry. or delete the registry entered for all monitors. those settings are in `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video`